# Unable to connect to mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am unable to connect to mysql db in python.

Code -

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="admin", passwd="1234")
```

Error -

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)
```

What can I do?

Comment: If you try to connect to this db with these credentials trough an interface like phpmyadmin for example, does it connect?

Comment: Looks like the the database Server is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused typically indicates that a network connection to a give host/port has failed because a) There is nothing listening on that port in given IP address or b) that port/ip combination is blocked by firewall. c) while a service (in this case, mysql) might be running in your local machine, it might not be binding itself to 127.0.0.1..

First, verify that first 2 of the cases aren't  happening.

You could try to use telnet to open a connection, something like this: `telnet localhost 3306` - if that gives similar "connection refused" - there's nothing wrong in your code *if* the server is supposed to be running on localhost and in that port.

Use of `netstat` could be also used to determine if any of your ethernet devices is listening on port 3306 ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Replace localhost to 127.0.0.1 as below:

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="admin", passwd="1234")